# Display only first heading of class with type

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

I have a list like this:

```html
<div class="list">
  
  <h3 class="type1">Type 1</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type1">Type 1 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 2 </h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 2 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 3 </h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 3 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  
</div>
```

There I have multiple headings (h3 with class type1, type2, type3).

I want to show only the first of each type.

How can I do this in css.

I can not add additional classes, I have to do it with the given html setup.

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no typo in your latest classes `type2` (where you have text saying "type 3") then you can use the general sibling selector `~` along with `nth-of-type`

```css
h3 {
  background: red /* demo */
}

h3:first-of-type~h3 {
  display: none
}

h3.type1~.type2:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <h3 class="type1">Type 1</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type1">Type 1 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 2 </h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 2 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 3 </h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 3 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>

</div>
```

---

If there is a typo in those classes you achieve it using the general sibling slector `~` in the same way but using selectors in a different way

```css
h3 {
  background: red/* demo */
}

.type1~.type1,
.type2~.type2,
.type3~.type3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <h3 class="type1">Type 1</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type1">Type 1 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 2 </h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type2">Type 2 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type3">Type 3 </h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <h3 class="type3">Type 3 to be hidden</h3>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM ---- ITEM</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. Just didn't get the idea I guess ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use this style

```
.type1 ~ .type1, 
.type2 ~ .type2, 
.type3 ~ .type3
{
    display: none;
}
```

THis is a general sibling selector

Answer (score 0):

`.list h3:nth-of-type(2n+1)` It will select first H3 element among others. using `nth-of-type` will select child by element type.